# DBFLow Where clause in query

Tags: dbflow

I am new to DBFLow.
I want to make aquery that returns one row depending on a where clause..I seem not to find a where clause with an and.

```
String phone = uname_pass[0];
String pass = uname_pass[1];

List<User> userList = SQLite.select().from(User.class).where("phone ?",phone ).execute();
```

I want to retrieve where `phone = uname_pass[0];` and `password = uname_pass[1]`;

What could be the right query ?

Answer (score 1):

1) **Synchronous:**

```
List<User> userList = SQLite.select()
                     .from(User.class)
                     .where(User_Table.phone.eq(uname_pass[0], User_Table.password.eq(uname_pass[1]))
                     .queryList();
```

Also you can write it like that (with ".and" in this case. You can choose ".or" and other operators instead of ".and")

```
List<User> userList = SQLite.select()
                     .from(User.class)
                     .where(User_Table.phone.eq(uname_pass[0]))
                     .and(User_Table.password.eq(uname_pass[1]))
                     .queryList();
```

2) **Asynchronous:**

```
SQLite.select()
    .from(User.class)
    .where(User_Table.phone.eq(uname_pass[0]),User_Table.password.eq(uname_pass[1]))
    .async()
    .queryListResultCallback(new QueryTransaction.QueryResultListCallback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onListQueryResult(QueryTransaction transaction, List<User> tResult) {

        //your list will be tResult
        }
    }).execute();
```